# AWS deployment without using SSH

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, webserver

I've read some articles recently on setting up AWS infrastructure w/o enabling SSH on Ec2 instances. My web app requires a binary to run. So how can I deploy my application to an ec2 instance w/o using ssh?

This was the article in question.

http://wblinks.com/notes/aws-tips-i-wish-id-known-before-i-started/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although doable, like the article says, it requires to think about servers as ephemeral servers.  A good example of this is web services that scale up and down depending on demand. If something goes wrong with one of the servers you can just terminate your server and spin up another one.

Generally, you can accomplish this using a pull model. For example at bootup pull your code from a git/mecurial repository and then execute scripts to setup your instance. The script will setup all the monitoring required to determine whether your server and application are up and running appropriately. You would still need an SSH client for this if you want to pull your code using ssh. (Although you could also do it through HTTPS)

You can also use configuration management tools that don't use ssh at all like Puppet or Chef. Essentially your node/server will pull all your application and server configuration from the Puppet master or the Chef server. The Puppet agent or Chef client would then perform all the configuration/deployment/monitoring changes for your application to run.

If you with this model I think one of the most critical components is monitoring. You need to know at all times if there's something wrong with one of your server and in the event something goes wrong discard the server and spin up a new one. (Even better if this whole process is automated)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Definitely helps, thank you. I'm currently using python fabric to push binaries to ec2 servers using elastic ips.... So I guess I'm doing it the non-automated way. I like the idea of each server on startup pulling the binary from a CI server though via HTTPs. That sounds very nice. I guess python fabric isn't as 'mature' as puppet or chef. But, it's also not as complicated it seems.

Comment: Fabric is pretty mature, but it uses more of the push model, whereas Puppet and Chef use the pull model.  If you look at other tools too, Ansible and SaltStack use more of a push model too.  You can use fabric to do pull from a git repository though if you just want to use the 'client' part of ssh on your server.

Comment: I see, so I'd define a fabric method to run on the remote server which pulls the binary from the CI server. That could work. In the future I will need to deploy many binaries across ubuntu and windows instances, and automated way of doing this would be very nice. Right now I'm pushing w/ fabric yes. I think a CI server is the answer here. I wouldn't need puppet, chef or fabric in that case. I could just define a script to pull binaries on startup of both the ubuntu and windows instances.

Comment: Yes, you could use straight up bash.  But if somehow you like fabric you could use that too.

Comment: I don't know how amazon auto-scaling works, but I'm assuming it clones the hard drive, which all the startup daemon configuration would get copied to. That's nice for web servers. I also have a standalone web socket server that all clients connect to. I can't have multiple of these since each one tracks connections, so I guess I'd just increment the instance's size... Not really fail safe. I guess I could have an internal load balancer for the web socket connections.... Or store the web socket connections in-memory that other machines could connect to....